# Could electrons exert pressure on a gas?

Tags: particle-physics, thought-experiment

What would happen if in a sealed chamber with a gas one injects electrons (by any means of emission)? Would the pressure in the chamber rise? What would happen to the gas (say H)? What would eventually happen if one keeps adding electrons?

Answer (score 1):

We model ideal gases as systems where interactions between particles are nonexistent.  But free electrons have long distance forces that are very large.  They don't create pressure in the same way because you can't get enough of them together to do so.  The gas here doesn't matter.  The effect is the same if you do this with gas in the chamber or in a vacuum.

A few free electrons in the chamber would repel each other strongly.  They would move to the wall of the chamber.  The electrons would then try to bond with the chamber material, forming ions.  If sufficient electrons were introduced, the electric field strength would rise until the chamber material failed (at the breakdown voltage for that material).

Long before the physical motion of the electrons could create a measurable pressure, the electrical field set up by them would destroy the system.